# Send Back SMS from Mobile to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, notifications, sms

I have a question about SMS functionality on AWS SNS.

I managed to send SMS from AWS to mobile, however, I cannot find a good way to send these SMS back to AWS. Is there any way to send SMS back to AWS from mobile?

Thanks in advance,
Ko

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

**Edit**: It seems you can do this, though the price may not be to your liking. See the docs for [AWS PinPoint](https://aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/what-is-two-way-sms/).

**Original Answer**:
There is no native way to receive SMS from a client in AWS. One way to achieve what you want is to investigate an SMS Gateway product (such as Clickatell, a popular SMS gateway vendor, who offer [inbound SMS functionality](https://www.clickatell.com/developers/api-documentation/rest-api-reply-callback/)).

Often times these vendors will allow you to pass your data in a RESTful way to your API using a callback, so you could use a Lambda or API Gateway in AWS to receive this information.

It is a little more complex than you might have been hoping, but it is definitely possible.

Comment: Hi James,

Understood that I cannot recieve SMS from client with AWS without using SMS Gateway vendor.
Thank you for your information.


Thanks,
Ko